# Do cats recognize cats from different litters but same parents?

Tags: cats, behavior, multi-pet-families, introducing-pets, biology

I adopted a kitten who is now 6 months old. His cat parents just had another litter and I want to adopt another kitten to be his buddy. Will he recognize that the kitten is related to him? I’m worried about the introduction and how well they will get along.

Answer (score 1):

If they have never met before, they won’t recognize each other as family, so you should expect introductions to go as they would with unrelated cats of the same ages. But kittens adapt relatively quickly, and they will both appreciate having a playmate once they realize the other isn’t a threat, so don’t take this as a reason to reconsider.